# What is the earth made of?

Tags: meaning, translation

I am looking for the traduction of the french word "*terre*". Which means the planet earth, the ground and also the material the ground is made of. I don't know how to translate a specific meaning of it, *this* :
[image]

Online translaters give me :

- *Earth* : Google image only shows the planet earth
- *Ground* : I don't know if this can be used to mean the material
- *Land* : I think that doesn't mean the material either
- *Dirt* : I think it means the "material" that make a thing dirty

What is the right translation for this ?

**Edit**

Example of sentence translated with google:

> Il y avait un tas de terre.
>  There was a pile of dirt.
>
> Il mit de la terre autour de la plante.
>  He put the soil around the
>   plant.

Comment: Perhaps, *[soil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil)*?

Comment: Could you write some example sentences and then translate them to English? That might help us understand the usage you are thinking of.

Comment: I added some example, does it change your answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Soil** is used mostly in farming/plants context - it's what plants grow in. You'll hear of "scent of wet soil", "good soil" (good for plants) etc.

**Dirt** is the common word used for the loose material ground is made of - you dig in dirt, you pile up dirt to form a ramp etc. You buy a bag of soil for your flowers, but you get a truck of dirt if you need to fill a hole or build a scarp.

**Ground** is what you walk on. You are on the ground level, the ground is firm under your feet etc. But you don't load a wheelbarrow of ground, you load a wheelbarrow of dirt you dug out from the ground.

**Land** is an area. You purchase a plot of land, and build a house on it. There is a land on the horizon - an island or a continent. A country is a land and its people. While ground is generic, local, land is more specific - the ground under your feet, but the land you live on.

**Earth** usually means our Planet Earth. In some cases it's used as synonym for soil/dirt, say, "rare earth metals", but this use (most common in poetic contexts) is definitely less common than 'planet Earth' and considerably less common than 'soil'.

Comment: It should be noted that it is not uncommon to use "earth" instead of "soil" to achieve a desired poetic effect, and that at least in the States, this definition is fairly well-known, if largely unused in day-to-day conversation and writing.

Comment: I agree with almost everything here. I'm just not sure I'd say that _earth_ "almost strictly" refers to the planet, or that it's "very rarely" found in other contexts.

Comment: @J.R.: Outside of poetic contexts, or archaisms, I wouldn't say it's anywhere close to frequent. Ngram doesn't have separation by meaning of synonyms, but [fertile earth, fertile soil](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fertile+earth%2Cfertile+soil&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfertile%20earth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfertile%20soil%3B%2Cc0) is a bit of indication of how frequently they are used, respectively.

Comment: @SF - "Not as frequent" ≠ "very rarely found" – that's all I was trying to say. The Ngrams depend on the context; check out [_the dry earth_ vs _the dry soil_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+dry+earth%2C+the+dry+soil&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), e.g. I agree that _earth_ often does have more of a poetic flavor.

Comment: @J.R.: As uncountable, earth=soil is very rarely prefixed with 'the'. Strip that, and you're getting a graph very similar to mine. We may disagree what comprises 'very rare', but if you include 'on earth' (a common expression for our planet) soil-related earth expressions land 3-4 orders of magnitude lower. But let's leave it at that - 'earth' may appear as a less common, poetically tinted synonym for 'soil'.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a question for a geologist, but anyway:

Most words we use in this way refer to the ground we can see and some small distance below that.

*Earth* (meaning the ground, not the planet), *ground*, and *dirt* all pretty much refer to this. * Soil* mentioned by Fantasier is also OK. In some contexts one may be a better choice than another.

*Land* is more often used in descriptions of surface areas of land or ownership.

Answer (score 1):

Even if Google images only shows the planet when you query `Earth`, let me assure you, the word *earth* is an apt description of what you seek. Check out what [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/earth) says:

[image]

If *earth* means "soil, ground, land," then it can be used to describe the picture you've included.

If you're looking for **only** what that person has in his hands, consider ***topsoil***.

---

That other option listed in meaning #2 might be of interest: ***terra firma***. NOAD defines that as:

> **terra firma** (*noun*)
>   dry land; the ground as distinct from the sea or air.

However, I think of that more like "firm land to stand on," rather than "rich soil to plant in."

Comment: Just some notes on the sentiments that the suggested alternatives here conjure: _topsoil_ has a bit of a scientific feel to it; the context that I most naturally picture it in is when someone is discussing how nutrients are distributed throughout different soil levels. _Terra firma_ is a bit abstract (the only modern context I associate it with is classifications of land under international law.)